# Why UTF-8 encoding doesn't need a Byte Order Mark?

Tags: encoding, utf-8

[Unicode FAQ](http://%20http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom5) mentions that UTF-8 doesn't need BOM.

> Q: Is the UTF-8 encoding scheme the same irrespective of whether the
> underlying processor is little endian or big endian?
>
> A: Yes. Since UTF-8 is interpreted as a sequence of bytes, there is no
> endian problem as there is for encoding forms that use 16-bit or
> 32-bit code units. Where a BOM is used with UTF-8, it is only used as
> an encoding signature to distinguish UTF-8 from other encodings — it
> has nothing to do with byte order.

For code points above `U+0744`, UTF-8 needs 2 to 4 bytes to represent them. Doesn't it need a BOM to specify the endianness of these bytes or does UTF-8 adopt a default?

Answer (score 6):

UTF-8 gives a strict definition for the order of the bytes that encode a character. No variation between computing platforms is allowed.

For example, the Euro sign U+20AC must be encoded as the byte sequence `\xE2\x82\xAC`. No other ordering of these bytes is permitted.

Answer (score 4):

UTF-8 uses 1-byte code units, so there is no need for a BOM to indicate a byte order, because there is only 1 byte order possible, and the encoding algorithm determines the ordering of the bytes.  For example, [U+0744](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0744/index.htm) is encoded in UTF-8 as code units `0xDD 0x84`, which are represented in bytes as `DD 84`.  Bytes `84 DD` would be an illegal UTF-8 sequence.

Unlike UTF-16 and UTF-32, which use 2-byte and 4-byte code units, respectively.  The encoding algorithm determines the order of the code units, but since the code units themselves are multi-byte, they are subject to endian. For example, U+0744 is encoded in UTF-16 as code unit `0x0744`, and in UTF-32 as code unit `0x00000744`, which are represented in bytes as `07 44` or `44 07` in UTF-16, and as `07 44 00 00` or `00 00 44 07` in UTF-32, depending on endian.

So, a BOM makes sense to indicate which endian is actually being used for UTF-16/32, but not for UTF-8.

Comment: That all makes sense, but note that _The  Unicode  Standard, Version  5.0_ states that BOM **is allowed** for UTF-8. See [_table 2.4_ in section _2.6 Encoding Schemes_](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.0.0/ch02.pdf#G19273), and the subsequent paragraph for an explanation of the special circumstances where it might be used.

Comment: @skomisa yes, use of a BOM in UTF-8 is *allowed*, but is generally *discouraged* in most uses, for compatibility reasons. And it is certainly not used for endian purposes (the focus of this question), only for identification purposes to distinguish it from other UTFs.